# How do you retrieve a tree structure using Room and a ViewModel with LiveData for use in RecyclerView containing sub-RecyclerViews?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, tree, android-room

I'm trying to retrieve a list of items of which each item can also contain sub-items (tree structure) in a Room database. I want to use these items in a RecyclerView that, depending on if the item has sub-items itself spawns another RecyclerView to contain these sub-items. The problem I have is how to correctly retrieve these items as LiveData. Within the database each item has a parent_id that points to the parent of the item.

```
@Entity(
    tableName = "items_table",
    foreignKeys = [ForeignKey(entity = Item::class, 
                              parentColumns = ["id"], 
                              childColumns = ["parent_id"], 
                              onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE)])
data class Item(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int,
    var parent_id: Int?,
    var name: String
    ... // Additional fields
)
```

I now retrieve the items with the DAO using 'getRoot' and 'getChildren':

```
@Dao
interface ItemsDao{
    @Query("SELECT * FROM items_table WHERE parent_id=:parent_id")
    fun findChildItems(parent_id: Int): LiveData<List<Item>>

    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM items_table WHERE parent_id IS NULL")
    fun getRoot(): LiveData<Item>
}
```

The items and subitems are now supposed to be used using an adapter for a RecyclerView

```
class ItemListAdapter(...) : RecyclerViewAdapter<ItemViewHolder> {

override fun getItemViewType(someItem): Int {
    return when someItem.hasChildren {
        true -> 0
        false -> 1
    }
}
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ItemViewHolder{
    val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
     when (viewType) {
        0 -> { // Item has children
            val inflated = // inflated with new recyclerView
            return ItemViewHolder(inflated, 0)
        }
        else -> { // Item has no children
            val inflated = // layout without new recyclerView
            return itemViewHolder(inflated, 1)
        }
    }
}
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ItemViewHolder, position: Int)
    // [...]
    when (holder.type) {
        0 -> {
            // Customize the view
            holder.itemView.recyclerView.adapter = ItemListAdapter(..., context)
        }
        else -> {
            // Customize the view
        }
    }
}
}
```

Since my database is accessed using a ViewModel and the Adapter does not have access to the ViewModel, how would I feed the items containing sub-items and their respective sub-items and so on with the LiveData conatining the respective children? Should I just pass the Dao or the viewModel to the adapter. In that case how do I observe the LiveData from within the Adapter since it isn't a fragment/activity? Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a perfect answer and I assume there are better ways (maybe at least using [transformations](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/Transformations)), but it works for now.

Instead of loading children using the database I simply observe the LiveData list and transform it when it changes to load into the adapters:

In fragment/activity:

```
viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ItemViewModel::class.java)

viewModel.items.observe(this, Observer {items ->
    val rootItem = items.filter { it.parent_id == null }
    for (item in rootItem) //There should be only one root item but filter returns a list
        item.populateChildren(items)
    adapter.setItems(rootItem)
})
```

The entities contain a method 'populateChildren(subList: List)' that recursively populates the @Ignore'd fields in the items creating a tree structure starting with rootItem and accessed via its children:

```
@Entity(
    tableName = "items_table",
    foreignKeys = [ForeignKey(entity = Item::class, parentColumns = ["id"], childColumns = ["parent_id"], onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE)])
data class Item(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int,
    var parent_id: Int?,
    var name: String){
    @Ignore var children: List<Item> = emptyList()

    fun populateChildren(items: List<Item>){
        children = items.filter { it.parent_id == this.id }
        for (child in children)
            child.populateChildren(items)
    }

}
```

This method simply does what the database did with 'findChildItems()' and matches the parentID of the items in the list with the parent's id.

The adapter contains a 'setItems()' method that uses 'notifyDataSetChanged()' for now (Not sure atm how to update this correctly).

```
internal fun setItems(sItems: List<Item>) {
        subList = sItems
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
```

Now in the onBindViewHolder of the adapter I propagate the children to the new recyclerView:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ItemViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val viewItem = holder.itemView
    val item : Item = subList[position]
    when (holder.type) {
        0 -> { // has children
            // Update viewItem
            // viewItem.[...] = item.[...]
            viewItem.recyclerView.layoutManager =
                LinearLayoutManager(context)
            viewItem.recyclerView.adapter = ItemAdapter(item.children, context)
        }
        else -> { // no Children
            val viewItem = holder.itemView
            // Update viewItem
            // viewItem.[...] = item.[...]
        }
    }
}
```

The adapter list can also be set when instantiated:

```
class ItemAdapter(var subList: List<Item>, val context: Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemViewHolder>() {
```

Comment: If you have "@Ignore" annotation the field is not saved by VieModel. Where do your children come from? I have a similar problem like you had but I get data from Retrofit and have to save ist to Room. If I just add foreign key like you did I get: "error: Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it". I don't know (yet) where there is the problem and what I can do...